# Magento : Page selection is missing with custom product list

Tags: php, model-view-controller, templates, magento, content-management-system

I have written a controller which generates a product collection based on the requested category and a attribute filter.

I generate the render with this code :

```
public function AfficherCollection($collection){
 if ($collection){
  Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($collection);       
  $magento_block = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');
  $productsHtml  = $magento_block->createBlock('catalog/product_list');
  $productsHtml ->setTemplate('catalog/product/list.phtml')->setCollection($collection);
  echo $productsHtml->toHTML();
 }  
}
```

The render works well but the problem is the page selector is missing.
But if I call my page with `?p=2` in page argument ; I have the desired products, so there are not any functional problems but still a page layout problem.

Have you got an idea ?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you totally bypassing the standard magento functionnalities and framework ?

You should use the Layout layer of magento framework..  It's him that handles all the product_list logic :

See for example catalog.xml layout file :

```
<catalog_category_view>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                    [...]
```

You can see that the pager is added by XML layout update

Comment: I'm beginner on Magento, i need to make a page which list all product  filtered by an attribute and have the categorie menu on left colum.
The attribute is a multi-select, i've done 99% of the project but i don't have page selection :(

Comment: Except one thing (attribute multi-selection), all the functionnality you need exists in standard magento. You only have to configure your catalog in the backoffice in order to have a list of product which have filterable attribute. You'll need to activate the "filter-category" too if you want to filter by category.. (or just modifiy the standard layout to display it on the left column)  No need to specific (and sorry, but ugly) coding to do that.

Comment: I don't want filter to be visible.
I want the category list on left only for this page but i'm lost :!

Comment: Sorry but you don't have a specific problem, you're just lost in magento complexity.. I would advise you to look at the tutorials / books and dive into the existing standard maegnto to understand all of its concepts :(